# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "G_OUTPUT" when expecting one of the following: :=

Tags: plsql

```
--script2.sql
--Krishan Billa
ACCEPT p_make PROMPT 'ENTER MAKE OF THE CAR';
ACCEPT p_model PROMPT 'ENTER MODEL OF THE CAR';
ACCEPT p_year PROMPT 'ENTER YEAR OF THE CAR';
ACCEPT p_color PROMPT 'ENTER COLOR OF THE CAR';
VARIABLE g_output VARCHAR2(500);
DECLARE
  CURSOR allprospects
  IS
    SELECT b.cname,
      TRIM(b.cstreet),
      TRIM(b.ccity),
      TRIM(b.cprov),
      TRIM(b.cpostal)
    FROM s9.prospect a
    INNER JOIN s9.customer b
    ON(a.cname         =b.cname)
    WHERE UPPER(a.make)=UPPER('&p_make')
    AND UPPER(a.model) =UPPER('&p_model')
    AND a.cyear        ='&p_year'
    AND UPPER(a.color) =UPPER('&p_color');
BEGIN
  :g_output := '&p_make'||CHR(10);
  FOR v_prospect IN allprospects LOOP
    :g_output := :g_output||'test';
    --:g_output := :g_output || v_prospect.cname || CHR(10)|| v_prospect.ccity || CHR(10);
    --:g_output := :g_output || v_prospect.ccity ||','|| v_prospect.cprov || ' ' || v_prospect.cpostal || CHR(10);
  END LOOP;
END;
PRINT g_output;
--select make,model,cyear,color,count(*)from s9.prospect group by model,make,cyear,color;
--desc s9.prospect;
--desc s9.customer;

--JAGUAR     XL       2016 RED          2
```

Please see the error below when i run this code. It looks pretty fine to me. Can anyone please help? Thankyou
    ORA-06550: line 24, column 7: 
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "G_OUTPUT" when expecting one of the following:     := . ( @ % ; 06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"

Comment: btw you should add some punctuation and space at the end of your prompt strings, e.g. `'ENTER MAKE OF THE CAR: '` otherwise entering a value will look like `'ENTER MAKE OF THE CARBMW'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the terminator SQLPlus is looking at the end of the plsql block. So the line "print g_output" is included in the block sent to the plsql "compiler". The compiler doesn't know what to do with it, and is not expecting it. That is the error. Try:

```
END;
/
PRINT g_output;
```